# Identify this graph problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request, terminology, operations-research

**[Edit 01/02/2021]** : Now the problem has been identified, as a relaxation of "**minimal spanning tree**" (it is more a minimal spanning sub-graph). **Are they some references I could use on this problem ?**

Let consider a graph made of $N$ nodes, numeroted from $B_1$ to $B_N$.

Each nodes can or cannot be connected to the other nodes, but overall we consider a family of weighed edges : $(\nu_{ij})_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} \in \mathbb{R}^{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}$.

The edges must be understood as followed :

- $\nu_{ij}=0$ if $B_i$ and $B_j$ are not linked by an edge.
- there is no edge connecting one node to himself.

I want to operate with a specific way on this graph (I want to select some specific edges), and I believe I am looking for a family of numbers $(x_{ij})_{1 \leq i < j \leq N}$ with $x_{ij}=0$ or $1$ that verifies the following discrete optimization problem :

$$\underset{(x_{ij})_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} \in (0,1)^{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}}{\min} \sum_{i<j}\  \nu_{ij} \  x_{ij}$$
with the following constraints on the $(x_{ij})$:

- $\sum_{i<j} x_{ij} = N-1$ (i.e we are only gonna keep $N-1$ edges in the graph)
- $\forall i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$, we have $$\sum_{j=i+1}^N x_{ij} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} x_{ji}  \geq 1$$ (i.e every nodes have at least one "non-zero" edge)

## My questions

Is this problem known in operation research or discrete optimization or is it closed to a known problema with a theoritical analysis ? I don't know a lot of them, except for **the traveling salesman problem** or **the cover set problem** but I am quite unfamiliar with them.

Separately from this first question, I believe (heuristically, at least) that any family $(x_{ij})_{1 \leq i < j  \leq N}$ admissible for this problem verifies the following property :

*the final graph with value $(x_{ij} \nu_{ij})$ on the edge is made of cycles and of only one path*

But i am not sure how to prove it. I'have been looking for counter-examples using $4/5$ nodes and cycle but couldn't find any...
Any help, references or remarks are welcomed on the problem :).

Comment: For $N=3$ with $v_{ij}=1$ for all $i$ and $j$, you can take $x_{11}=x_{23}=1$ and $x_{ij}=0$ otherwise. This yields the minimum of $0$ with $N-1=2$ edges and all vertices meeting one of these edges. However there exists no such pair $(i_0,j_0)$.

Comment: You mean $x_{11}=x_{23}=1$ i guess ? Thank you for your comment since it helped me realized that the problem is not set as I want it to be. I will make some modifications.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I meant. I edited my comment accordingly.

Comment: Do you require that $x_{ij}$ can only be $1$ when $ij$ is an edge of the graph?

Comment: Yes indeed, and 0 if its not.

Comment: Then it would be better to set $v_{ij} = +\infty$ (instead of $v_{ij} = 0$ when the edge is absent from your graph. This makes it clear that, in the linear problem formulation, you don't want a $x_{ij} = 1$.

Also, the case where there are $v_{ij} < 0$ can be forgotten : by adding a constant offset to all the edges (so that all edges are positive), which will only add a constant value to the $\min$ but won't change the choice of the $x_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume here that your edges' costs are in $\mathbb R_+^* \cup \{+\infty\}$)

First, you can remove the $\Sigma x_{ij} = N+1$ constraint.
If you have a minimum-cost solution, it will be a forest covering all the nodes (since if there was a cycle, you could remove its biggest edge, and the "non-zero degree" constraint will still be preserved at a better cost).
Given this minimum-cost solution, if you want to add edges to add up to $N+1$ edges, you can use the smallest edges that aren't used yet.

So now you just need a minimum-size edge cover of the vertices, and this has a polynomial solution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover)
EDIT : The Wikipedia page only cites the problem with constant-valued edges. A polynomial solution also exists for the real-valued one : see [*Plesník, Ján*, [**Equivalence between the minimum covering problem and the maximum matching problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(84)90170-5), Discrete Math. 49, 315-317 (1984). [ZBL0581.05045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0581.05045).]

Concerning the shape of the solution, it turns out that, in this minimum-cost forest, you won't have a 3-length path. If you have a chain $u - v - w - x$ then the same forest without the $(u,v)$ edge still works for the constraints and has a lower cost. So the solution is a collection of trees whose diameter is 1 or 2 : those are stars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)).
But then, you just fill it with the smallest edges you get, so you could have any graph shape.

Comment: Hi @Hugo Manet, thanks a lot for your answer and the references. However I'm not sure I understand the first thing you said. I believe the constraint $\sum x_{ij}=N-1$ must be conserved. As a counter-example, see the graph :                                                                                                      x ---1--- y ---2--- z ---3--- v                    When you keep the constraint $\sum x_{ij}=N-1$, the solution is the tree that covers every edges : (x-y-z-v). If you don't keep the constraint, the solution is the forest (x-y) (z-v), which is different. What do you think ?

Comment: Hi ! What I meant is : you can first solve a (different) problem without the $N-1$ constraint, which will give you a solution with $k \le N-1$ edges. Then, you have $|E| - k$ unused edges remaining, and all your constraints are satisfied. So you take the smallest remaining edges (because it is the best for the cost function), until you reach the number you want. And this solution is optimal for your original problem.

Comment: I understand your point now, thanks. But don't you agree that when you had the last remaining edges to go up to $N-1$ edges selected, the shape of the solution is a forest with only one path and cycles ?

Comment: Not really, no. The minimum edge cover might have $\frac N 2$ edges,  so you have up to $\frac N 2 - 1$ edges that are selected not because of the connectivity they provide, but only because of their cost value. So maybe they could create simple cycles, and maybe they could create arbitrarily big cliques... But for examples with 4/5 nodes it might be complicated to see this arise. Try the graph with nodes ${0,1,...,99}$ and edge cost $v_{i,j} = i + j$ : one solution is all the edges $(2k,2k+1)$ plus all the smallest edges, and you have a clique of size probably 8 or 9 at low-indexed nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relaxation of the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) (MST) problem.  The connectivity requirement of MST has been replaced with a "no isolated nodes" requirement in your problem.